# Zend Framework ACL Roles and Modules

Tags: zend-framework, acl

I am going insane trying to distinguish between the Index controller and Index action in my Admin Module and the Index controller and Index action in my Default module using ACL.

I want logged in users to be able to have access to the Default Module's index controller but not the admin module at all.  No matter what I try, if I allow access to the default module's index, the admin modules index is available as well.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your resources as `module-controller` and privileges as `action` then you can have something like this

```
...

// Default module, index controller
$this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('default-index')); 
// Admin module, index controller
$this->addResource(new Zend_Acl_Resource('admin-index'));

// Allow user to access default module, index controller, index and about actions
$this->allow('user', 'default-index', array('index', 'about'));
// Allow admin to access admin module, index controller, all actions
$this->allow('admin', 'admin-index');

...
```

[EDIT] And in your controller plugin predispatch

```
    ...

    $module = $request->getModuleName();
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $action = $request->getActionName();
    $resource = "{$module}-{$controller}";
    if ($acl->has($resource)) {
        if (!$acl->isAllowed($role, $resource, $action)) {
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I've been trying that...  The code below gives me the following error...

`  $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('admin-index'));
  $acl->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('default-index'));
  $acl->deny();
  
  $acl->allow('guest', 'default-index', array('index'));
`

`
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Acl_Exception' with message 'Resource 'index' not found' in /Users/drewfulton/Dropbox/Websites/Parulidae/library/Zend/Acl.php:365`

Comment: I added section of the controller plugin for ACL. Here you need to construct your resource using the module name and the controller name before checking if user is allowed or not.

Comment: That did it.  The problem I was having was in the second if statement, as I was using $controller rather than the $resource definition you provided.  Thanks for all the help.  Huge saver!